# Proving a set is linearly independent in $C([0,1])$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, continuity

Let C([0, 1]) be the vector space of continuous real-valued functions on [0, 1]. I am trying to show that any basis for C([0, 1]) must be uncountable. I have defined a function by, for $s \in (0,1)$, $$g_{s}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{x}{s} & \text { if } 0 \leq x \leq s \\ \frac{1-x}{1-s} & \text { if } s<x \leq 1\end{array}\right.$$

I am trying to show that the set $P = \left\{g_{s}: s \in(0,1)\right\}$ is linearly independent.

What I have so far is: $P$ is not finite. So, to prove that $P$ is linearly independent, we need to prove that every finite subset of $P$ is linearly independent. Therefore, we can take any $m$ elements, for example, $\{ g_{s_1}(x), g_{s_2}(x),\dots, g_{s_m}(x)\} $ where $x \in [0,1]$. If  there are scalars $\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \cdots, \alpha_{m} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\alpha_1 g_{s_1}(x) + \alpha_2 g_{s_2}(x)+\dots + \alpha_m g_{s_m}(x)=0$$ then it must be that all $\alpha$'s are zero. I'm not sure where to go from here though.
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: One possible approach: show that if $\alpha_i \ne 0$ (and all $s_i$ are distinct), then $\alpha_1 g_{s_1}(x) + \cdots + \alpha_m g_{s_m}(x)$ is not differentiable at $s_i$.